# I Searched For A long Time And I Tried All Ways About The Backendless Problems But I didn't Find Any Answer & I'm Using (Swift 4.2)

Tags: ios, swift4.2

here is the problem :

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   ___isPlatformVersionAtLeast, referenced from: -[Backendless Push Helper create Request From Template:request:] in lib
>   backendless.a(Backendless Push Helper.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for
>   architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to link `backendless` against your app?

Comment: Yes, I used Backendless pod in my project

Comment: Can you check the version linked contains the method in the error?

Comment: The Version Of The Selected Pod "Backendless"  : swift4.2" & Other Pods Is also Swift 4.2 @fizzybear